# command inside $() in bash script

Tags: bash, export, debian

I'm new to linux. I'm seeing a bash command (is that even the right term?) that sets `JAVA_HOME` environment variable at the prompt:

```
export JAVA_HOME =$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java |sed "s:bin/java::")
```

I know what the command inside `$()` does. But what is the `$()` for? It failed if I didn't include it.

Obviously googling `$()` doesn't work very well.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html - it's called command substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used to get the output of the `readlink` command. For example:

```
cnicutar@lemon:~$ os=$(uname)
cnicutar@lemon:~$ echo $os
Linux
```

Answer (score 4):

`$()` is called command substitution. It replaces the output of a command with the command itself.
There are basically two ways you can do command substitution:

```
$(command)
```

or with backticks

```
`command`
```

The first variant is the preferred one.

You can read more about command substitution [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `$(...)` expression runs a command and substitutes the output of the command.  Try something like this:

```
echo $(date)
```

So in this example, it's taking the output of the `readlink` command and assigning it to `JAVA_HOME` (after running it through `sed`).

Look at the `bash` man page for more deatails.

Comment: The explanation is good, but the example would be the same as "date" by itself.